# Display Image from website in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

why that code work in WinRT but not in Windows Phone 8.1?

```
foreach (var img_url in imagesList)
        {
            image = new Image();
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(img_url, UriKind.Absolute));
            image.Width = 300;
            image.Height = 300;
            pnlImages.Children.Add(image);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
foreach (var img_url in imagesList)
            {
                image = new Image();
                image.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(img_url));
                image.Width = 300;
                image.Height = 300;
                pnlImages.Children.Add(image);
            }
```

Hope it helps!